# Apache2: userdir module

Tags: apache2, virtual

Recently, I installed Apache2 on mu Ubuntu machine (http://www.example.com) and I enabled userdir module. I wanted to know what userdir module actually does behind the scene. As I can access http://example.com/~theuser by properly configuring userdir module, does that mean it creates a virtual box for the specific URL http:/ /www. example. om/ ~theuser? If not, how virtual box concept is different that creating an URL http: //www. example. com/ ~theuser using userdir module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Userdir module just maps the `/~username/` urls to each user's own `public_html` directory or any other user specific directory you have configured. That's not a virtual box, it's just alias for a directory in a single web server.